# Нужна ли запятая перед "как" в данном примере?

Tags: запятые

Пример:
Представьте Женю(?) как (в виде) учительницу класса

Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не нужна.

> 4. Сравнительный оборот с союзом *как* не выделяется запятыми: (...) 3) если союз *как* имеет значение ‘в качестве’ (...): *Богат, хорош собою, Ленский везде был принят как жених* (П.); *Итак, я вам советую как приятель быть осторожнее* (Л.); *Я говорю как литератор* (М. Г.)
>
> http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147,3

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните. Глагол «представить» – многозначный, в каком значении он здесь используется (познакомить или вообразить)? Или здесь возможно только одно значение?   А если возможны оба, то  это может повлиять на постановку запятой?

Comment: @Sharon Для варианта "вообразить" некорректная структура, но, судя по "в виде", он и задумывался.

Comment: Пожалуй, вы правы. По крайней мере для такого значения (представить, вообразить) можно подобрать ситуацию, где это предложение используется.